# Can I declare and initialize an array with the same instruction in Java?

Tags: java, arrays, initialization, declaration

Is there a way to do the following at the same time?

```
static final int UN = 0; // uninitialized nodes
int[] arr;

// ... code ...

arr = new int[size];
for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
    arr[i] = UN;
}
```

Basically, I want to declare `arr` once I know what its size will be and initialize it to `UN` without having to loop. So something like this:

```
int[] arr = new int[size] = UN;
```

Is this possible?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, not with the standard libraries. If you write your own functions, though, you can easily do so in a single statement (not instruction; those are different). Mine looks like `String[][] strings = Arrayu.fill(new String[x][y], "");`

Here's a [link](http://pastebin.com/zm4wqwbt). There's some junk in there too, though; I just posted a copy of the current source directly without cleaning it up.

Comment: This looks interesting. Does this still loop through the indices behind the scenes?

Comment: Of course. That's the only way it can be done. (btw: java.lang.Arrays loops through the indices too, but it also does bounds checking even when you just call `Arrays.fill(arr, UN)`. It's kinda stupid like that.)

Comment: Thanks for you answers. I won't use this `Arrayu` since I'm trying to avoid extra "stuff" and I'll resort to my for loop. But your answer is best so far... so I'll accept it.

Answer (score 4):

```
Arrays.fill(arr, UN);
```

Comment: Although you should be aware that behind the scenes, that's going to do the same loop you were trying to avoid.

Comment: -1 I think the point is to avoid the extra code. Also, you can't use that to do it in a single statement because it doesn't return the array.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to initialize them with `0`. An `int` defaults to `0` already.

Just

```
int[] array = new int[size];
```

is enough. It gives you an array of zeroes of the given length. If it were an `Integer[]`, it would have been an array of `null`s.

Comment: .. thanks. I actually asked another question that this is the answer for. So thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

Well, in the case of objects (or primitives with autoboxing) you can do the following:

```
int count = 20;
final int UN = 0;
Integer[] values = Collections.nCopies(count, UN).toArray(new Integer[count]);
```

The downsides are that you have to use the object forms of the primitives (since the Collections must be of objects) and a separate List will be constructed and then thrown away. This would allow you to create the array as one statement however.

Answer (score -1):

Oops, read your question better:

You can init an array like so

```
int[] arr = new int[] {UN, UN, UN, UN, UN};
```

But ofcourse, if you don't know the size at compile time, then you have to do the for loop. The second technique is not possible.

Comment: Only if you know what size it's going to be, and that size will never change.

Comment: I don't know the size of it to begin with... so I can't do `{ UN, UN, UN }`. I will eventually know the size but it will be in a variable

Answer (score -1):

No.

Next question?

Comment: .. Ok. Well... is it possible to initialize an array of size n in O(1)?

Comment: @Vuntic... In C you can do `int[5] arr = 0;` right? Isn't that O(1)?

Comment: "No" is a perfectly legitimate answer to "Is it possible".

Answer (score -1):

```
int arr[] = { 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 };
```

Comment: .. I didn't downvote you. Sorry for that. I hate it when it happens to me. But as far as your answer goes, I know that... the problem is I don't know the size, it is in a variable.

Comment: Thanks for telling me you didn't down vote me, but no worries. Yes, if you don't know the size, you have to initialize in a loop, *unless* the number you want to initialize to is zero -- as zero is the default value for int. (Not for Integer; it's defualt is null)