# Declare and initialize an array in Java

Tags: java, arrays, null, initialization, declaration

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Can I declare and initialize an array with the same instruction in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3426668/can-i-declare-and-initialize-an-array-with-the-same-instruction-in-java)

How to declare an array in Java, while initializing some known elements of it?
firstly this method declare but doesn't initialize elements:

```
public static someClass myArray[] = new someClass[10]; // all values are null,
```

now imagine I know the first element's value but not the others, it's after some logic that I assign values to them
the second suggestion would be:

```
public static someClass[] myArray = {new someClass(),null,null};
```

so this instruction works but it's not practical to do the same with an array of 200 elements

Comment: what exactly do you mean by initilizing its 1st value ?

Comment: Provide values with which to initialize it.

Comment: Re your edit; what's the bad solution? You could also just initialize the first element in a static block, or in the code, or...

Comment: why heavily down-vote this question,

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Initialize it in a static block, of course:

```
static {
   str st[] = new str[10];
   for (int i = 0; i < st.length; ++i) {
     st[i] = new str();
   }
}
```

Everyone else is assuming that your `str` means `java.lang.String`.  I'm not.

I'll point out that your naming and coding conventions are rather poor.  I'd recommend following the Java coding standards and thinking harder about good names for things.

Comment: You could just do `static str[] strs = { new str(), new str()... }` too :) But +1 for not making a silly assumption.

Comment: (If it's a big array, OTOH, the block is likely more appropriate, obviously.)

Comment: OK, this static block will surely help, thank you all!

Answer (score 13):

```
public static String st[] = new String[]{"foo", "bar"};
```

Comment: Can you please explain a bit more of why this is the correct answer?

Answer (score 3):

Try the following:

```
public static String st[] = {"a","b","c"};
```

Comment: what is the difference between declaring this way you declared and declaring like this public static String st[] = new String[] {"a","b","c"};

Answer (score 2):

You mean

```
public static String st[] = new String[] { "a", "b", "c" };
```

Comment: (Of course, if it's really `String`, you can just use `public static String st[] = { "ohai", "kthxbai" };`)

Answer (score 1):

```
 public static String st[] = {"firstValue",null,null,null}
```

or

```
public static String st[] = {"firstValue","second","third","fourth"}
```

Comment: how about using the static block as in the above answer by @duffymo

Comment: it's hard to write a lot of nulls? when we have an array of size equals 100

Comment: @user1951298 You don't have to write a lot of nulls, use a static block or code to initialize just the first element.

Comment: Why cant you use like this , st[0] = "firstValue";